# How does one set useragent for phantomjs driver in selenium-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Is it even possible ? I currently have :

```
 require 'selenium-webdriver'

 phantomjs_useragent = {"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3"}
 driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
 driver.capabilities.merge!(phantomjs_useragent)
 driver.navigate.to "http://whatsmyuseragent.com/"
 puts driver.first(:tag_name => 'body').text
```

That gets me, which is not the user agent I put in :

Your User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.8.1 Safari/534.34

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's possible. Request made at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5078

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this suggestion](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/8):

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.phantomjs("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" => "Custom Agent/1.0")
Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs, :desired_capabilities => capabilities
```

Was merged for selenium-webdriver-2.31 and later